# Polynomial satisfying $ P \big(P (x)\big)=P (x)+ P\big(x^2\big)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, polynomials, contest-math, functional-equations

If $P(x)$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients such that for all integer $x$, $$P (P (x)) = P (x)+P (x^2).$$ 
I've tried solving it putting it as a function instead. Not much though. How do you find such polynomials?

Comment: Rollback to version 4. the question in version 5 is totally unclear. In general, if your question have received answers, you should not completely change it to the point which make existing answer meaningless. If you have another question, please ask a new one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hints. First note that either $P\equiv 0$ or it is a second degree polynomial, with leading coefficient 1.

To do this, observe first that if $P$ is constant, then $P\equiv 0$.

Next, if the degree $d$ of $P$ is at least 1, then the degree of the left-hand side of 
$$
P(x)+P\big(x^2\big)=P\big(P(x)\big),
$$
is $2d$, while the order of the right hand side is $d^2$, and thus $2d=d^2$, i.e., $d=0$ or $d=2$.

Next, if $a_2x^2$ is the leading term of $P$, then the leading term of the left-hand side is $a_2x^2$, while leading term of the right-hand side is $a_2^2x^2$.

Hence $P(x)=x^2+ax+b$. Then plug this in the equation to determine the values of $a$ and $b$. Now, the third order term in the left hand side is zero, while in the right-hand side is $2ax^3$. Thus $a=0$. It is not hard to get that $b=0$, as well.

Answer. It turns out that $P\equiv 0$.

Comment: thanks! how do I prove that this a second degree polynomial?

Comment: cool now i get it thx.

Comment: oh and why is the leading coefficient 1 btw?

Comment: so this is what I got: 2ax^3+x^2(a^2+2b)+x(a^2+2ab-a)+b^2+ab-b=0. Does it follow that a=0 and b=0?

Comment: @JackiePoehler: Correct.

Comment: could you pls explain why a=0 and b=0 follows? It just seemed intuitive to me

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis

Comment: I think now it is clear.

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis thank you

Answer (score 2):

Let the polynomial be of degree n $P(P(x))$ has a maximum degree $(x^n)^n$ i.e., $n^2$ and on the right hand side similarly it has a max degree of $2n$. So now compare this max degrees $n^2=2n$ which implies n =2. Now try solving it by considering the polynomial as quadratic.